# How to dispatch a thunk from a saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I know I shouldn't be trying to dispatch thunks from sagas, it goes against what redux-saga tries to do. But I'm working in a fairly large app and most of the code is made with thunks, we are migrating by bits and need to dispatch a thunk from inside a saga. The thunk can't be changed because it is used in other parts (a thunk that returns a promise), so it would break many things.

configureStore:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(applyMiddleware(thunk, sagaMiddleware))
);
```

Saga:

```
// Saga (is called from a takeEvery)
function* watchWarehouseChange(action) {
  const companyId = yield select(Auth.id);

  // We use cookies here instead of localStorage so that we persist
  // it even when the user logs out. (localStorage clears on logout)
  yield call(Cookies.set, `warehouse${companyId}`, action.warehouse);

  // I want to dispatch a thunk here
  yield put.resolve(syncItems);
  // put(syncItems) doesn't work either
}
```

Thunk:

```
export function syncItems() {
  console.log('first!');

  return dispatch => {
    console.log('second!');

    return dispatch(fetchFromBackend()).then(
      items => itemsDB.emptyAndFill(items)
    )
  }
}
```

Whenever `syncItems()` is executed, only `first!` logs. `second!` never happens.

PS: I don't get any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using `syncItems` wrong.  The key is that the *function returned by `syncItems`* needs to get passed to `dispatch`, not `syncItems` itself.  The correct usage would be:

```
yield put(syncItems());
```

I showed some visual comparisons of how values are passed into `dispatch` in my blog post [Idiomatic Redux: Why use action creators?](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/) (based on [an example gist I put together](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/6c7608eee5d2421966d3df5edbb8f05c)).  Here's the examples:

```
// approach 1: define action object in the component
this.props.dispatch({
    type : "EDIT_ITEM_ATTRIBUTES", 
    payload : {
        item : {itemID, itemType},
        newAttributes : newValue,
    }
});

// approach 2: use an action creator function
const actionObject = editItemAttributes(itemID, itemType, newAttributes);
this.props.dispatch(actionObject);

// approach 3: directly pass result of action creator to dispatch
this.props.dispatch(editItemAttributes(itemID, itemType, newAttributes));

// parallel approach 1: dispatching a thunk action creator
const innerThunkFunction1 = (dispatch, getState) => {
    // do useful stuff with dispatch and getState        
};
this.props.dispatch(innerThunkFunction1);

// parallel approach 2: use a thunk action creator to define the function        
const innerThunkFunction = someThunkActionCreator(a, b, c);
this.props.dispatch(innerThunkFunction);

// parallel approach 3: dispatch thunk directly without temp variable        
this.props.dispatch(someThunkActionCreator(a, b, c));
```

In your case, just substitute `yield put` for `this.props.dispatch`, since you're dispatching from a saga instead of a connected component.

Comment: Thanks @markerikson, you are absolutely right! It was way easier than I thought

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation of [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/) and specifically call and put:

[call:](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callfn-args)

> fn: Function - A Generator function, or normal function **which either returns a Promise as result**, or any other value.

[put:](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#putchannel-action)

> Creates an Effect description that instructs the middleware to put an **action** into the provided channel.

Technically a thunk returns a Promise, which is why you can `await` a dispatch of a thunk:

```ts
export declare type AsyncThunkAction<Returned, ThunkArg, ThunkApiConfig extends AsyncThunkConfig> = (dispatch: GetDispatch<ThunkApiConfig>, getState: () => GetState<ThunkApiConfig>, extra: GetExtra<ThunkApiConfig>) => Promise<ReturnType<AsyncThunkFulfilledActionCreator<Returned, ThunkArg>> | ReturnType<AsyncThunkRejectedActionCreator<ThunkArg, ThunkApiConfig>>> & {
    abort(reason?: string): void;
    requestId: string;
    arg: ThunkArg;
};
```

This means you can do the following to dispatch a thunk from a saga:

```ts
yield put(
  yield call(syncItems)
);
```

The `call` method returns the redux `action` of your `syncItems` saga, which will be used by the `put` method to dispatch your action.

Answer (score 0):

use https://github.com/czewail/bind-promise-to-dispatch package

add resolve and reject paramers in saga func

then use this package func wrap this.props.dispatch

then you can use it with promise